# Issue connecting to Google Cloud SQL with Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When I try to connect to Google Cloud SQL via the Cloud Shell, I get the following error:

```
gcloud beta sql connect mysql-1 --user=root
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.connect) You do not have permission to access instance [mysql-1]: The client is not authorized to make this request.
```

I am not sure what permission is required to grant this access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that I typed in my project name incorrectly when configuring the CLI.

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: ran into the same issue after upgrading the components. A quick way to check which project you're using is: `gcloud config get-value project`